# provision functions inside a function app with a null_resource provisioner

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

I am trying to provision 2 functions inside a function app with a null_resource provisioner, this is how the null_resource looks like

```
resource "null_resource" "functions" {

  triggers = {
    functions = "${local.version}_${join("+", [for value in local.functions : value["name"]])}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
    cd functions/
    func azure functionapp publish ${local.app_name}
    cd ../
    EOT
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
  }

  depends_on = [azurerm_function_app.core]
}
```

and the azure devops step looks like this:

```
 #Apply
- bash: terraform apply deployment.tfplan
  displayName: Terraform Apply
  workingDirectory: dev/terraform/
  env:
    ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(kv-arm-subscription-id)
    ARM_CLIENT_ID:       $(kv-arm-client-id)
    ARM_CLIENT_SECRET:   $(kv-arm-client-secret)
    ARM_TENANT_ID:       $(kv-arm-tenant-id)
```

But I see two problems:

1- it's not finding the functions folder, although it's inside

[image]

2- it's returning an error that it can't connect to azure, this is the full error message:

```
│ 
│ Error running command 'cd functions/
│ func azure functionapp publish my-app-gt-test5345
│ cd ../
│ ': exit status 1. Output: bash: line 0: cd: $'functions/\r': No such file
│ or directory
│ Unable to connect to Azure. Make sure you have the `az` CLI or
│ `Az.Accounts` PowerShell module installed and logged in and try again
│ bash: line 2: cd: $'../\r': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `working_dir` input parameter for the [local-exec provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html) instead of using `cd functions/`.

Your code would then look something like (untested):

```
resource "null_resource" "functions" {

  ...

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "func azure functionapp publish ${local.app_name}"
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
    working_dir = "${path.module}/functions"
  }

  depends_on = [azurerm_function_app.core]
}
```